# React Native app's expo-sqlite callback not executed until app refresh

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-sqlite

I have a simple app that makes a connection to a sqlite database, reads results from that database, and displays them. Here is the app:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';


async function openDatabase() {
  if (!(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite')).exists) {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite');
  }
  await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/banana-dict.db')).uri,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/banana-dict.db'
  );
  return SQLite.openDatabase('banana-dict.db');
}


export default function App() {
  const [ dicts, setDicts ] = useState([]);
  const [ db, setDb ] = useState({
    transaction: () => {
      return {
        executeSql: () => {},
      };
  }});

  const updateDicts = (a) => {
    setDicts(
      Object.fromEntries(a.map(({rowid, ...rest}) => [rowid, rest]))
    );
  }

  const fetchDicts = () => {
    console.log('fetch')

    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `select rowid, * from dicts;`,
        [],
        (_, { rows: { _array } }) => { console.log(_array); updateDicts(_array); }
      );
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    openDatabase().then((value) => {
      setDb(value);
      fetchDicts();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
      <Text>Open App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(dicts)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

`banana-dict.db` is a preexisting database I'm using for this app.
I've found that if I start the app and open it on my phone, the `dicts` state (ie, results of a query on the db) do not appear. However, if I press `r` in the console for a refresh, the results appear immediately.
Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app starts, the initial `db` value is set. The first effect batches `setDb` and `fetchDicts`, so `db.transaction` has not been updated with the value of the `setDb` call. Because Expo has stateful refresh, the `db` is no longer set as the initial value but has the result of `setDb`, so `fetchDicts` works, and the results appear.

One way to fix this would be to move `fetchDicts` into its own effect, and call it when `db` changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  openDatabase().then((value) => {
    setDb(value);
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchDicts(); // will do nothing until db connection is open
}, [db]);
```